# Django Query with getting all the item in manytomanyfield

Tags: django-models, django-orm

This is my models:

```
class Persons(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Persons,
        related_name='group_members'
    )
```

I am trying to get all the group members like this:

```
p = Persons.objects.select_related('group_members').values('id')
```

and it returns all the Person id, this is the problem.

I want only person id who are in any of the group members..

Can anyone help me in this case?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to make a title for the group like this

```
class Group(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

and then make a group for example name it 'GOT fans', then assign it to multiple users.

then select all the 'Persons' in that particular group like this

```
gotFansIDS = Group.objects.filter(name="GOT fans").values('id')
```